# How to enable Grilo UPnP plugin in rhythmbox?

Tags: rhythmbox, plugins, streaming, upnp

The newest version of rhythmbox (**2.95**) should have a [Grilo UPnP plugin](http://projects.gnome.org/rhythmbox/rhythmbox-2.95.news), but I can't find it in Rhythmbox and it is not enabled or available by default.
I installed rhythmbox 2.95 according to this [instruction](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/rhythmbox-finally-ported-to-gtk3.html) in Ubuntu 11.10.
The [rhythmbox-plugin-coherence](http://coherence.beebits.net/wiki/RhythmBox) is not in the normal repositories anymore and so I thought it would be great to have the new rhythmbox version with pre-installed (?) Grilo plugin instead of installing from another repository.

Or do I need to install the Grilo plugin with [another repository](https://live.gnome.org/Grilo) (ppa:grilo-team/ppa) in Ubuntu?

Update July 2012:
Did anybody try it with Rhythmbox 2.96 (or via ppa Rhythmbox 2.97) in Ubuntu 12.04 and the the Grilo plugin (from ppa:grilo-team/ppa)?
With the normal install of Rhytmbox **2.96 and 2.97** (without additional Grilo plugin from the ppa:grilo-team/ppa) I have not seen any UPnP support. I have not had time to install the Grilo plugin yet.

Update October 2012
No grilo UPnP plugin with rhythmbox 2.98 (via ppa).

Comment: I got an answer, but ...: If the plug-in is installed properly it should appear on the list when you select Edit > Plug-ins. The PPA may be the best way to get the latest updates and no matter what method you use make sure the plug-in is compatible with the version of Ubuntu and Rythmbox in use .As you know Rythmbox is not the default player in 11.10.

Comment: But: If I understand you right, I have to install the grilo plugins (grilo-0.1-plugins) in addition to the new rhythmbox.
Or should it come along with the new rhythmbox installation (through the ppa:webupd8team/rhythmbox)?
Well, I installed grilo-0.1-plugins (with libgrilo-0.1 (0.1.18-1~oneiric2), libgupnp-av-1.0-2 (0.8.0-2), libtracker-sparql-0.10-0 (0.10.24-1build2), libunistring0 (0.9.3-4)) from the ppa:grilo-team/ppa. Unfortunately there has not been an new
plugin (e.g. Grilo plugin) within rhythmbox (Edit>Plug-ins).
So I added grilo-0.1-tools, then gir1.0-grilo-0.1, but no effect neither.

Comment: How do I know whether the plug-ins are compatible with Ubuntu 11.10? What next?

Comment: It seems that nobody knowledgeable read this post so far, so I tried to install the rhythmbox-plugin-coherence package, but was not successful, either. This is leads to the [next question.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/110498/how-to-enable-upnp-coherence-plugin-in-rhythmbox-2-95-in-ubuntu-11-10)

Comment: i think you need to compare current Ubuntu version against current Upstream version.  It is unlikely Ubuntu has the absolute latest Rythmbox version.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you on?

Comment: Just updated the question. I installed the newest version 2.97 but no success in Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this howto](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506142649/http://www.bernaerts-nicolas.fr/linux/74-ubuntu/240-ubuntu-precise-upnp-dlna-client).

I got it working myself quite well after that...

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @Peter The installation of the grilo plugin works great. But I was disappointed as I thought rhythmbox would share the music on the computer to other clients, e.g. an Mediaplayer-box. But it seems that the plugin only helps to receive UPnP-music and let it play in rhythmbox. :-(

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 18.04, I had to install `rhythmbox-plugins` (which provides the [Grilo](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/Grilo) plugin) and `grilo-plugins-0.3-extra` (which provides upnp/dlna plugins for grilo)

Answer (score 0):

For all those who cannot find http://www.bernaerts-nicolas.fr/ (I do not know, maybe it gives the answer, but the web service is non existent).

**For grilo-plugins to see DLNA** they depend on `dleyna` server d-bus service - which is the thing that allows actual interaction with DLNA servers. If you do not have dleyna installed, grilo won't show your home DLNA server.

more info: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/rhythmbox/-/issues/1793

I use arch, but the same thing should apply to debian derivatives.

When grilo plugin is installed, `dleyna-server` is not automatically installed as it is listed as an optional dependency. As soon as dleyna is installed, restarting rhythmbox gives it ability to see your DLNA server.