# How to enable UPnP coherence plugin in rhythmbox 2.95?

Tags: 11.10, rhythmbox, streaming, plugins, upnp

In Ubuntu 10.10 I was using the `rhythmbox-plugin-coherence` package and I was happy to stream music from Rhythmbox to our internet radio box. But in 11.10 (64Bit) I can not find the package anymore, although [this page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/+source/rhythmbox) claims it is in the repositories (as far as I understand).
I first tried Rhythmbox 2.95 which should have a Grilo UPnP, but was not successful.

So installed the plugin according to [this link](http://coherence.beebits.net/wiki/RhythmBox) with Rhythmbox 2.95:

```
sudo apt-get install subversion  
sudo apt-get install python-coherence  
sudo svn checkout https://coherence.beebits.net/svn/trunk/Coherence/misc/Rhythmbox-Plugin/upnp_coherence/ /usr/lib/rhythmbox/plug
```

ins/upnp_coherence

And I also tried:

```
svn checkout https://coherence.beebits.net/svn/trunk/Coherence/misc/Rhythmbox-Plugin/upnp_coherence/ /home/cds/.gnome2/rhythmbox/plugins/upnp_coherence
```

But there is still no UPnP Plugin to activate in Rhythmbox (Edit>Plugins).
Did anybody manage to install this in Ubuntu 11.10 or does this plugin not work anymore with the newer versions of Rhythmbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Coherence plugin does not install in newer versions of rhythmbox

A debian package [rhythmbox-plugin-coherence](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/+package/rhythmbox-plugin-coherence) built for 11.10 can be found on launchpad (see link). However this package depends on rhythmbox <0.14 and will not run with a newer version of rhythmbox. This may not change in the future as both the coherence plugin and the debian package is not included for 12.04.

#### Alternatives

- **DAAP shares from Rhythmbox:**
  We are able to share our music by defining a DAAP share from the DAAP plugin in rhythmbox (*Edit->Plugins*):

  [image]
- **[uShare](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/ushare) [image: Install ushare]**
  Another quite stable solution for UPnP shares is the command line tool uShare that also works independent of a running music player. After set up with

  ```
  sudo dpkg-reconfigure ushare
  ```

  we can share any directory or multiple directory by running

  ```
  ushare -D --name=<name_of_my_stream> --content=<path_to_mediafiles>
  ```

  In case you are not so comfortable with the command line there is a GUI tool [stream2ip](https://launchpad.net/stream2ip/+download) that will do most of the work for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the speedy answer! DAAP does not work for me, but ushare (sudo apt-get install ushare) could be configured with dpkg-reconfigure and I added to the start-up applications, wonderful. The actual folder system is available now on my internet network radio.

Comment: Stream2ip offers streaming of playlists what is a cool feature. I will try to configure it when I have time. I liked the possibility in XBMC to browse through the collection by different tags (Genre, artists, compilations, recently added albums, ...), but I have not found a way to run it in the background.